# How to shine a dull mark on granite worktop?

Tags: kitchen-counters

I have a scratch on a black granite worktop which I have buffed away with a Dremel polishing piece and some 2000 grit sandpaper, however the area has lost its shine/lustre compared to the rest of the granite.

The scratch is gone and the affected area is completely smooth but it looks a little grey compared to the original surface - see the following photo:

[image]

The affected area is about 1cm in length so is relatively small. How can I restore the shine to this area?

Answer (score 1):

Countertops to my knowledge are polished to 3000G and polished with flowing water using special equipment. I have made my own tops and finished the edges using dry polishing pads, and I have seen a minor difference. Your biggest difference you may see is the dull surface from the sealer being removed from your polishing.
Find yourself a silicone based, color enhancing stone sealer, and it may do just what you need.